# Windows 7 does not detect my new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios

I just built a really nice new PC.

Some specs...

Intel i7-930 CPU
ASRock Extreme X58 motherboard with sata 3 and USB 3.0
12gb of G-Skill DDR3 RAM
80gb Intel G2 Solid state drive for Windows 7 and other programs to run on
Windows 7 Pro 64bit OS
2 1gb graphic cards for 4 monitor support

Thats the main components.

Well today my new 1tb western digital hard drive came which I plan to use for data to preserve the life of my SSD (hopefully).

I hooked up it's sata power input and then hooked up it's sata data cable to a sata 2 port on my motherboard, I boot windows 7 and go into my computer and the drive is not showing up with my other drives.  I then re-boot again and check again, no luck.  I then shut down the PC and open the case back up, I then check my connections and they all look good.  I then boot up and I can see the new HD is on and spinning.  I then go into my BIOS settings to see if it registers there and it DOES!  It shows I have a WD 1tb hard drvie on sata 2 port 6.

So I am at a loss of why it is not showing up as an option in windows?  Windows acts as if the drive is not there.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need to initialize and format the disk through disk management.  It should be in Administrative Tools in the Control Panel.

Comment: I just did this.  I googled and found that tip as you posted this and got it working so you were on the right track.  Thanks I will also post an answer with more info for others who might search and find this question someday as a reference

Answer (score 3):

Based on the same answer that Holocryptic posted.

***1)***
I went to the Windows 7 **Start menu** and clicked it, then I typed in **diskmgmt.msc** into the search box that says "Search programs and files"  **diskmgmt** should come up as the search result and click on it to open it up.

***2)*** 
From this disk management program I was able to find my 1gb drive and right click it and format and assign a drive letter to it.

***3)***
Once done it shows up as a working drive, very simple!

Comment: Drives come absolutely clean as you don't know if it will be put in a Mac, Linux, Windows, or other system. Every OS has a number of file systems they support as well. So the usual steps are 1)physically install, 2)partition, 3)format, 4)assign drive letter or mount point.